# non-unique id from ews

Tags: coldfusion, exchangewebservices

I was using EWS to create a new calendar event. All of that seems to work just fine, but I wanted to add additional functionality to modify or delete the event. As a result, I was looking back at the unique ID I was storing, and I realized that the ID is always the same. Regardless of the event. If I create 10 in a row, they are always the same. Different dates, different content, etc - all the same ID. That is making me think that I am getting the unique ID correctly. Here is the code:

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
<cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment" name="appointment">
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SendInvitationsMode" name="invite">
<cfobject type="Java" action="create" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody" name="mb">
<cfobject type="Java" action="create" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.BodyType" name="mbt">

<cfset service.init()>
<cfset credentials.init("[username]","[password]")>
<cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />
<cfset uri.init("[url]")>
<cfset service.setUrl(uri) />

<cfset appointment = appointment.init(service) />
<cfset appointment.setStart(createDate(Year(now()), Month(now()), day(now())) />
<cfset appointment.setEnd(createDate(Year(now()), Month(now()), day(now()))) />
<cfset appointment.setSubject(" Test Appointment") />
<cfset appointment.setIsAllDayEvent(true) />

<cfset mb.setBodyType(mbt.Text) />
<cfset mb.setText("Loaded by [name] on #dateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")#") />
<cfset appointment.setBody(mb) />

<cfset appointment.Save(invite.SendToNone) />

<!--- Both give the same results --->
ID: <cfdump var="#appointment.getId()#" />
ID: <cfdump var="#appointment.UniqueId.ToString()#" />

<!--- 
Result is always
AAMk ... AAA=
 --->
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something silly in how I'm retrieving the IDs. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

- EDIT *

I should also point out that when I add contacts ...

[contact mangling code]

```
<cfset contact.Save() />
ID: <cfdump var="#contact.getId()#" />
```

I get the exact same ID as the calendar events. Makes me think I'm actually getting an ID some something more high level like the service or something.

Comment: You appear to be displaying only irrelevent code.  The code for setId() would be much more useful than all those cfobject tags.  Also, how are these Id's being generated?

Comment: Well, that's probably where I am going wrong. How do you set the IDs? I thought there were automatically generated during the appointment.save() method? Am I understanding that incorrectly?

Comment: Any other feedback out there???